# Why would AICc be less than AIC?

Tags: r, model

My general understanding of AICc is AIC is modified for small samples so that we are less "certain" about a model with few samples, and that as the sample size gets very large, the modification approaches 0 and we become more "certain" (excuse me if I use incorrect terminology). However, I've encountered an issue when using the `AICc` function in the 'AICcmodavg' package to calculate AICc for a null model (y = mx + c; m = 0) I'm comparing to others. Here you can see that AICc is supposedly smaller than the AIC:

```
library(minpack.lm)
library(AICcmodavg)

y = c(80,251,304,482,401,141,242,221,304,243,544,669,638)

mNull <- nlsLM(y ~ c, start=c(c=mean(y)))
```

And when I run the AIC functions:

```
> AIC(mNull)
[1] 175.6431
> AICc(mNull)
[1] 169.6431
```

The help file says the AICc should be calculated as: −2∗log−likelihood+2∗K∗(n/(n−K−1)), but when I try to calculate it by hand:

```
> k=AICc(mNull, return.K = T)
> n=length(y)
> -2*as.numeric(logLik(mNull))+2*k*(n/(n-k-1))
[1] 176.8431
```

Meanwhile, calculating AIC by hand seems to work correctly:

```
> AIC(mNull)==-2*as.numeric(logLik(mNull))+2*k
[1] TRUE
```

So conceptually, why would AICc be less than AIC? Both n and k in this instance wouldn't lead to a negative modifier. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way that `AICc.nls()` calculates the number of observations.  It uses the length of the fitted values if `nobs` is not supplied.  In your case, this is 1 (not the length of `y`).  So, if you supply `nobs` to `AICc()`, you'll get the right answer.

```r
library(minpack.lm)
library(AICcmodavg)
y = c(80,251,304,482,401,141,242,221,304,243,544,669,638)

mNull <- nlsLM(y ~ c, start=c(c=mean(y)))
#> Warning in .swts * attr(rhs, "gradient"): Recycling array of length 1 in vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.
#>   Use c() or as.vector() instead.

fitted(mNull)
#> [1] 347.6923
#> attr(,"label")
#> [1] "Fitted values"

AICc(mNull, nobs=length(y))
#> [1] 176.8431

k=AICc(mNull, return.K = T)
n=length(y)
-2*as.numeric(logLik(mNull))+2*k*(n/(n-k-1))
#> [1] 176.8431
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The relevant piece of code from `AICcmodavg:::AICc.nls()` (where `nobs=NULL` is the default) is:

```r
    if (identical(nobs, NULL)) {
        n <- length(fitted(mod))
    }
    else {
        n <- nobs
    }
```

Comment: This "infelicity" seems worth reporting to the package maintainer ...

Comment: @BenBolker true, but which one?  On the one hand, `AICc.nls()` could throw a warning if n=1 or n less than some arbitrary threshold.  Alternatively, perhaps it would be good if a null model estimated with `nls()` returned a constant vector of fitted values of length `y`.

Comment: I posted the issue on the R-devel mailing list (as suggested in the bug reporting guidelines) and also e-mailed the maintainer of AICcmodavg.